# How to change webpage zoom based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

Hi so I created a web page that looks fine on my desktop monitors. When I viewed the page using a laptop, the page looks abnormal. However, when I zoom the page to 67% it appears fine. Both my monitors and my laptop has the same resolution, 1920 x 1080, but my monitor is bigger than my laptop's one. I know that i can change zoom in CSS but it would look bad on my pc. I was wondering is there a way to change zoom based on screen size in javascript or CSS.

Comment: This is not an easy question. Maybe the devicePixelRatio can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio Best, Paul

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries) in your CSS to change the styles that get applied depending on the size of your screen. You could have one set of styles that works for larger screens like your PC, and another that applies for smaller screens like your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with JavaScript if you include the viewport meta tag in your HTML.

```
if (document.body.clientWidth < /*screen width pixels*/) {
  viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.67, user-scalable=0');
}
```

You can substitute the properties below with different values to test out what works for you.

`initial-scale` property controls the initial zoom level (possible range between 10%-1000% or 0.1-10.0).

`user-scalable=0` prevents users from zooming

Comment: Can i ask what should i put as the screen width pixels in the if statement

Comment: You can try inserting the width of your monitors since the web page looks fine on them. E.g. if (document.body.clientWidth < 2048) {...}

Comment: Although keep in mind that this code snippet is just a small proof of concept. For full coverage, you will likely need to write various conditionals for many other screen resolutions. Unless you only need to specify zoom for your presonal laptops, another solution you can look into is working with media queries in CSS like @timtim17 mentioned.